# Two (SELECT TOP 1 +1 ) statements and two INSERTS same time

Tags: sql-server, database, transactions

What happens if while a transaction is executing, another client computer does an insert?

I have two client computers and one DB. These computers have the same program on them. Let's say we have order table and salesorder# column, this column is UNIQUE.

If both computers execute at the same time I know SQL server will select one of the transactions and make the other one wait. So this transactions does following

```
@ordernumber= SELECT TOP Salesorder# +1 .
 INSERT INTO order (salesorder#,dateship, user) VALUES (@ordernumber,GETDATE(),1,)
```

I Believe that if both happened at the same time, it would just choose one of then , run completely, and then do the same for the other one. Is that correct?

What happens in a different scenario. If the transaction Begins, and another INSERT ( not a TRANSACTION Just INSERT statement) is requested after after the SELECT Statement but before the INSERT happens.

What will SQL Server do in that situation? Is this even possible?

Comment: AFAIK, SQL Server will lock the row being inserted.  If another process tries to insert a record with a unique identifier which already exists in the table, or is in the process of being inserted, the second insert should fail.

Comment: Ok so even if the transaction is started, i will not lock the insert until the actual INSERT statements begins. what if two transactions are executed at the same time

Comment: From what  I have read, an insert or update by itself typically won't lock the entire table, unless something else is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One word: ***DON'T DO THIS!!*** This **WILL** fail - for sure.

Assuming you have a table with the highest number of 100 - now you have two (or several) concurrent user requests to do an insert.

Both requests will first read the highest number (100) and each will increment it by +1 - so both have a value of 101 internally. The `SELECT` statement will only do a quick **shared lock** - but both `SELECT` **will work** and will read the value of 100. Whether or not they're inside a transaction makes no difference here - just because there's a transaction **doesn't stop** a second `SELECT` from happening.

The `INSERT` *will* in fact create an exclusive lock - but **only on the row** being inserted (**NOT** the whole table!). There's nothing from stopping both concurrent requests from inserting their new row, and both will attempt to insert a row with `salesorder#` value of 101. If you do have a unique constraint on this, one of the requests will **fail** since the other request has already inserted a value of 101.

This is one of the many reason you should **NOT** handle giving out sequential ID's manually - let the database handle it, by using an `INT IDENTITY` column, or a `SEQUENCE` object.

Comment: Thank you very much, what would you recommend?  I could have my identity column is indexed, and Unique(handle by the DB) then columns, salesorder#(Unique because we need to have a unique salesorder. But how to do the insert increasing by 1 and preventing a fail insert. my goals is to have. unique salesorder and to prevent a fail. ( right now what they have here it's if the sales order (window) it active then, that already lock other user from opening another one. which is not use full at all.

Comment: @JuanG: using an `INT IDENTITY` column means: you don't have to provide a value - the SQL Server database engine will. Your `INSERT` just doesn't mention the identity column at all - and concurrent inserts are guaranteed by the SQL Server engine to get separate `salesorder#` values.

Comment: I understand that fact, but i can't use the identity the because if the salesorder insert, fails for any other reason which could happen. then lets say im at primary key 100, then if it fails, next one it will be 101 and , then the number salesorder(100) will never exist, which is not good for accounting.

Comment: can't something be done line this for example,  SELECT salesorder#, IF INSERT fails, then SELECT salesorder# again, and try the INSERT again with the new value? that way preventing the fail.  or  something like. Id(IDENTITY), Salesorder(NOT UNIQUE)    SELECT, THEN INSERT, Then Check IF Duplicate, IF not unique, SELECT TOP 1 +1, UPDATE the row with new VALUE?

Comment: @JuanG: ***DO NOT DO THIS MANUALLY*** - period. Forget about the gaps - those are **NOT** a problem. Duplicates are - and you can **avoid** duplicates by using `IDENTITY`- so in my opinion, which way to go is crystal clear ....

Comment: Perfect then we will have to do that, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@marc_s thanks for you help , I believe  found a way to follow your recommendation (since you crearly know what you are talking about ) and the same time have salesnumbers in a way I wanted.

Our software architecture  centers in a gateway . So we have clients , sending command to a gateway and then the gateway communicates with SQL SERVER. What I will do, is to prevent the gateway from sending an INSERT command  to the same table at the same time by giving priority to clients differently.

For example: if we have clients compuerta let's call it  1,2,3 . Do the same action at the same time. (I know is technically impossible that this happens ) I can give the priority to 1 then once 1 is finished 2 will execute and then 3 . I know this  is not a solution thru SQL because but this way I will prevent a fail insert, and I will be able to keep IDENTITY  for salesorder#. Limiting the times that a fail insert would happen to almost 0.

Once again thanks for all the help and explainations a per why not to INSERT the way I wanted to do before. Any books recommended for reading on DB information?